# VS2022 Licence expiring

Tags: visual-studio

I keep getting this message saying that my VS2022 licence is about to expire (now in 5 days) and I'm a bit freaked out because I am a legit user who purchased it!  It mentions using a product key which I can't see in my account, and Microsoft docs offer no help at all!  Has anyone solved this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you didn't activated it? You say you purchased it. Then take the code you received and insert it to activate VS

Comment: I'll search around to see if I can activate it.  I didn't get a code - only a receipt number.